# How to select 5 successive rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got a table with several trs. I want to select 5 trs in a row and give them a background color, then take the next 5 trs and give them another background color - like even and odd, but with 5 elements as a block.

This is what I have tried

```js
var trs = $('table.small-only tr');
for (var i = 1; i < trs.length; i += 5) {
    if (i%2 == 0){
        // select even blocks
    }else {
        // select odd blocks
    }
}
```

This doesn't work though.

How can I select blocks containing 5 trs and give the even and odd blocks different background colors in a proper way?

I found a work around:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < trs.length; i += 5) {
    trs.slice(i, i + 5).wrapAll("<div></div>");
}
```

and

```css
div {
    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background: #f2f2f2 !important;
    }
}
```

But clearly putting divs around trs in a table isn't a good way.

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: how you are selecting `<tr>` ? can you show html structure ?

Comment: Please can you also show the relevant ("*[mcve]*") HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can loop through the `tr` elements in the table stepping over the number of rows you want per group. You can then use `slice()` to retrieve the set number of rows before calling `addClass()` on them. Try this:

```js
var groupSize = 5;
var classes = ['group1', 'group2'];
var $rows = $("table.small-only tr");

for(var i = 0; i < $rows.length; i += groupSize) {
  $rows.slice(i, i + groupSize).addClass(classes[i / groupSize % classes.length]);
}
```

```css
.group1 { background-color: #C00; }
.group2 { background-color: #0C0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="small-only">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ah appeared whilst I was typing mine out! weird how we've both gone red green blue too!

Comment: Get rid of one of the classes in the array. I'll update the example.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my example:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

var my_table_rows= $('.my-table tr');
var color;
for (var i = 0; i < my_table_rows.length; i++){
 if (i % 5 === 0) color = getRandomColor();
  my_table_rows.eq(i).css('background', color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-table">
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td></tr>
  <tr><td>9</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>11</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>13</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td></tr>
  <tr><td>15</td></tr>
  <tr><td>16</td></tr>
  <tr><td>17</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: though your code is selecting blocks of 5, it's not setting a different background colour for the even/odd ones, try adding something that devides the index of the table by to, if a the answer is a round number then it's even, if not, it's odd

Answer (score 1):

> but clearly putting divs around trs in a table isnt a good way

No, it is invalid html. However you can use `<tbody>` instead of `<div>`

A table can have any number of `<tbody>` elements

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that way

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
   <tr><td>test</td></tr>
   <tr><td>test</td></tr>
   <tr><td>test</td></tr>
   <tr><td>test</td></tr>
   <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
  <tr><td>test</td></tr>
 <tr><td>test</td></tr>
 <tr><td>test</td></tr>
 <tr><td>test</td></tr>
 </table>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
 var limit = 5;
 var arr = ['red','green','yellow','blue','orange'];
 $('.table tr').each(function(i,e){
     var ind = parseInt((i/limit));
     $(this).css('background',arr[ind]);
 })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS selector `:nth-child(xn)` and `:not()`:

```
tr:nth-child(10n - 5)~ tr:not(:nth-child(10n + 1)):not(:nth-child(10n + 2)):not(:nth-child(10n + 3)):not(:nth-child(10n + 4)):not(:nth-child(10n + 5)) {background-color:gray}
```

```css
tr {
  background: turquoise;
  counter-increment: trs;
}
tr:nth-child(10n - 5)~ tr:not(:nth-child(10n + 1)):not(:nth-child(10n + 2)):not(:nth-child(10n + 3)):not(:nth-child(10n + 4)):not(:nth-child(10n + 5)) {
  background: tomato
}
/* check row numbers */

tr:before {
  content: counter(trs);
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: solid;
  background: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(odd):before {
  background: gray;
}
td {
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```